# Having trouble with mutator methods

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, methods, mutators

This method is to sum up all the numbers present on the dice and add them to the  total score. There are 5 dice, I'm having trouble with it because whenever I activate it through the GUI it just adds some random numbers together and not the numbers present, also I can activate the button without rolling and it gives me numbers still.

`dieList` is the `ArrayList` that carries the current die numbers, and `nextRound` just puts the game to the next round. If you require more information I will be happy to supply it.

```
public void checkChance(){

   int chance = 0;
    for(GVdie die: dieList){
     chance = chance + die.getValue();
     score = score + chance;
    }
    nextRound();
 }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, a website where you can get help on specific problems with code. Start with the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and what questions are [suitable for asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and which ones are [not](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). In this case, you need to post more code. The code that you have posted will work completely fine without the `nextRound()` method. Read [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: it seems the function return `void` and `score` don't get used, is it the whole function? what again is the problem?

Comment: Can you show the code for the getValue() method? How do you generate the value of each dice?